# Account History Track custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, accounthistory

I have created this custom object. Problem is for say Account ID A1 if Lastname field was X now becomes Y. It creates an entry for this with Old value X new Value Y. Now if again updated by Z, the same AccountHistory record updated with a new value of Z and old value of Y. I need separate entries for each update. My code so far is:

```
trigger AccountHistoryTracker on Account (after update) {
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.HistoryTracking.getFields();
    if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;

    List<AccountHistoryTracking__c> fieldChanges = new List<AccountHistoryTracking__c>();

    List<string> apiNameList = new List<string>();        

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (Account aNew : trigger.new) {

            Account aOld = trigger.oldmap.get(aNew.Id);

            for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) {

                String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
                String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel();

                if (aNew.get(fieldName) != aOld.get(fieldName)) {

                    String oldValue = String.valueOf(aOld.get(fieldName));
                    String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));

                    AccountHistoryTracking__c aht = new AccountHistoryTracking__c();
                    aht.name         = fieldLabel;
                    aht.apiName__c   = fieldName;
                    aht.User__c      = aNew.Id;
                    aht.ChangedBy__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    aht.OldValue__c  = oldValue;
                    aht.NewValue__c  = newValue;
                    aht.createddate__c = system.now();

                    apiNameList.add(aht.apiName__c);
                    fieldChanges.add(aht);
                }        
            }
        }
    }
    if (!fieldChanges.isEmpty()) {
        insert fieldChanges;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and it is creating separate entries for me. Is there any chance you have set any of the fields to be external id?

Comment: You are right my friend!!! I am sorry it is fine now!! Actually I am really a beginner here. :)

Comment: Presumably you have a reason for building this yourself rather than using the existing [Tracking Feld History](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US) platform feature?

Comment: Yes Friend. Salesforce provide OldValue and Newvalue with length 255. I have to track fields having field length larger than that.

Comment: I wrote similar code to build my own history tracking but I was wondering if you ever extended your code to write not the reference ID but the reference Name of an lookup.